# Java Custom Barrier Implemenation

Tags: java, multithreading, barrier

First off, this is Homework, so I am only looking for a hints and pointers of where to perhaps look.

I intend to create multiple processes and send them through a barrier

Main.java

```
for (int x=0; x!=threadCount+1; x++){
            Process newThread = new Process(barrier, x, sleepTime);
            newThread.run();
        }
```

Process.java

```
public void run() {
        try {

            Thread.sleep(100 + sleepTime);
            barrier.joinBarrier(this);

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
```

and then my Barrier.java

```
public synchronized void barrier() throws InterruptedException{
        wait();
    }

    public synchronized void releaseBarrier(){
        notifyAll();
    }

    public void joinBarrier(Process p) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(p.getName() + " waiting on barrier");

        if(blocking){
            threadsWaiting++;
            barrier();
            releaseBarrier();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(p.getName() + " passed the barrier");
        }
    }
```

Perhaps my understanding is flawed but I expected that the first thread would wait, then the second thread would wait however my output just stops,  the thread is forever waiting

```
Number of threads = 20
Barrier size = 10
Thread 0 waiting on barrier

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I think my understanding of how this is supposed to work is close, but I'm missing something. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

wait simply waits and notifyAll wakes all waiting thread up. So if you call

```
wait();
notifyAll();
```

this will never terminate since the thread waits at wait and no thread will every reach notifyAll. There is a canonical form for using wait, notifyAll (see Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz et al). Here is this form:

```
synchronized{    // always execute the complete block in a synchronized block to avoid race conditions
    execute the action // as first update the count or whateverto mae sure that this will be done everytime
    notifyAll  // then inform all other threads about the change
    while( ! conditionTrue ) // now check the condition in a loop
    {
       wait(); // wait till the condition becomes true
    }
}
```